# Cannot resolve: PurchasesResult, queryPurchases, getPurchasesList

Tags: android, android-studio, android-billing

I'm trying to convert android billing version 3 to android billing version 5.
But I have a problem in this function, I have no idea how to change it to make it work:

```
@Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if(billingResult.getResponseCode()==BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                    Purchase.PurchasesResult queryPurchase = billingClient.queryPurchases(INAPP);
                    List<Purchase> queryPurchases = queryPurchase.getPurchasesList();
                    if(queryPurchases!=null && queryPurchases.size()>0){
                        handlePurchases(queryPurchases);
                    }
                    //if purchase list is empty that means item is not purchased
                    //Or purchase is refunded or canceled
                    else{
                        savePurchaseValueToPref(false);
                        removepremium();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Cannot resolve: PurchasesResult, queryPurchases, getPurchasesList...

How can I change this to work in billing 5?